# Xcode7: This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes

Tags: ios9, xcode7

I got this messages,when I updated Xcode7. Can you tell me solution? Thank.

**This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.  This will cause an exception in a future release.**

```
Stack:(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x250df883 <redacted> + 150
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x367dedff objc_exception_throw + 38
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x250df7b1 <redacted> + 0
    3   Foundation                          0x25f7be63 <redacted> + 170
    4   Foundation                          0x25e21ba7 <redacted> + 38
    5   UIKit                               0x292f3aa9 <redacted> + 52
    6   UIKit                               0x292f4487 <redacted> + 222
    7   UIKit                               0x299ccfa5 <redacted> + 288
    8   UIKit                               0x294e5fa9 <redacted> + 148
    9   UIKit                               0x291ed6bb <redacted> + 694
    10  QuartzCore                          0x28ab967d <redacted> + 128
    11  QuartzCore                          0x28ab4d79 <redacted> + 352
    12  QuartzCore                          0x28ab4c09 <redacted> + 16
    13  QuartzCore                          0x28ab4129 <redacted> + 368
    14  QuartzCore                          0x28ab3deb <redacted> + 590
    15  WebCore                             0x34a9c79f <redacted> + 282
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x250a2827 <redacted> + 14
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x250a2417 <redacted> + 454
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x250a077f <redacted> + 806
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x24ff31e9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 516
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x24ff2fdd CFRunLoopRunInMode + 108
    21  WebCore                             0x34040cdf <redacted> + 422
    22  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x37077c93 <redacted> + 138
    23  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x37077c07 _pthread_start + 110
    24  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x37075a24 thread_start + 8
)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I don't know what your code is, but I have an idea as to why this is happening. You must be having some UI changes done in a background thread.

> Do not change UI from anything but the main thread, it is bound to
>   make your application unstable, and crash unpredictably.

### Use GCD (Grand Central Dispatch).

You can listen and do work from any thread, and encapsulate UI changes in a dispatch_async:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Do UI stuff here
});
```